# Google Fit sleep tracking integration error

Tags: android, google-fit

I have tried to implement sleep tracking using GoogleFit and it return the error

com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException: 5000: Application needs OAuth consent from the user

Here is my code for fetching the sleep data:

```
private fun readSleepData() {
    val request = SessionReadRequest.Builder()
        .readSessionsFromAllApps()
        // By default, only activity sessions are included, so it is necessary to explicitly
        // request sleep sessions. This will cause activity sessions to be *excluded*.
        .includeSleepSessions()
        // Sleep segment data is required for details of the fine-granularity sleep, if it is present.
        .read(DataType.TYPE_SLEEP_SEGMENT)
        .setTimeInterval(periodStartMillis, periodEndMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build()


    val sessionsClient = Fitness.getSessionsClient(this, getGoogleAccount())
    sessionsClient.readSession(request)
        .addOnSuccessListener { response ->
            for (session in response.sessions) {
                val sessionStart = session.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                val sessionEnd = session.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                Log.i(TAG, "Sleep between $sessionStart and $sessionEnd")

                // If the sleep session has finer granularity sub-components, extract them:
                val dataSets = response.getDataSet(session)
                for (dataSet in dataSets) {
                    for (point in dataSet.dataPoints) {
                        val sleepStageVal = point.getValue(Field.FIELD_SLEEP_SEGMENT_TYPE).asInt()
                        val sleepStage = SLEEP_STAGES[sleepStageVal]
                        val segmentStart = point.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        val segmentEnd = point.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        Log.i(TAG, "\t* Type $sleepStage between $segmentStart and $segmentEnd")
                    }
                }
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
        Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem fetching the session", e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sleep data are part of the restricted types under Google Fit. You'll need to have a valid OAuth token to use with your requests so that you can access and write the said data type.

The following are a list of restricted types under Fit([source](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#verification-types&circumstances&skip&verification-time&mark-internal&submit-who&submit-howto&api-scopes&select-scopes&check-verification&how-smooth&in-app-testing-video&in-progress-addition&data&i-do-not-publish-for-review&rejected&why-seeing&verified-but-app-disabled&pending-app-disabled&definition&restricted-scope-apis&restricted-def&prep-for-next-year&when-restricted&enterprise&enterprise-security-assessment-notification&enterprise-imap-or-smtp&migrate-to-new-scopes-and-minimize-impact&key-dates&how-long&several-apps&combo-scopes&faster&verification-requirements&addl-scopes&how-often&guidelines&task-automation&not-type&restricted-not-allowed&explain-types&inconsistent&privacy-policy-language&multiple-types&compliance-with-limited-use-requirements&needed&how&user-data-not-restricted&assessment-includes&more-detailed-sec-reqts&why-fee&local-client&restricted-scopes-expansion&third-party&recently-completed-sec-assess&no-vulnerability-disclosure-program&security-assessment-not-required&how-long-sec-assess-valid&after-receive-loa&reassessment-prep&security-rewards-program-definition&security-rewards-program-criteria&security-rewards-program-process&security-rewards-program-sla-noncompliance&security-rewards-program-unfixed-bug&questions&check-user-cap&complete-test&deployment-access&zippy=%2Csteps-for-apps-requesting-sensitive-scopes%2Csteps-to-prepare-for-verification%2Csteps-for-apps-requesting-restricted-scopes%2Csteps-to-submit-your-app%2Csecurity-assessment%2Cwhat-are-the-different-types-of-verification-that-google-requires-for-accessing-user-data-via-oauth%2Cwhen-does-my-app-have-to-be-verified-by-google%2Cwhat-app-types-are-not-applicable-for-verification%2Chow-long-will-the-verification-process-take%2Chow-can-i-mark-my-app-as-internal-only-so-it-doesnt-require-verification%2Cwho-can-submit-a-project-for-verification%2Chow-do-i-submit-for-verification%2Cwhy-cant-i-see-the-api-scopes-in-the-scope-picker%2Ci-need-help-selecting-scopes-for-my-app-where-can-i-find-support-for-various-product-apis%2Chow-do-i-check-my-verification-status%2Chow-can-i-make-sure-the-verification-process-is-as-streamlined-as-possible%2Cwhat-information-should-i-include-in-the-in-app-testing-video%2Cwhat-happens-if-i-add-new-sensitive-or-restricted-scopes-to-my-app-while-my-sensitive-or-restricted-scope-verification-is-in-progress%2Chow-can-i-access-data-from-my-users-google-cloud-project-using-cloud-apis%2Cwhat-happens-if-i-dont-submit-my-app-for-review%2Chow-do-i-check-my-user-cap-status%2Cwhat-happens-if-my-app-gets-rejected-from-the-verification-process%2Cwhy-are-users-seeing-this%2Cwhy-are-users-of-verified-apps-seeing-the-unverified-app-screen-or-sign-in-disabled%2Cwhy-are-users-of-apps-that-are-currently-in-the-verification-process-seeing-the-unverified-app-screen-or-sign-in-disabled%2Cwhat-are-sensitive-api-scopes%2Cwhat-are-restricted-api-scopes%2Cwhat-is-the-restricted-scope-app-verification-and-how-is-it-different-from-the-sensitive-scope-app-verification%2Chow-can-i-prepare-for-a-restricted-scope-verification%2Chow-do-i-determine-if-i-need-to-submit-my-app-for-restricted-scope-verification%2Cmy-application-has-users-with-enterprise-accounts-from-another-google-workspace-domain-how-does-this-apply-to-my-google-workspace-or-cloud-identity-enterprise-accounts%2Cwhat-if-my-app-is-using-imap-or-smtp-do-i-need-to-submit-for-verification%2Chow-do-i-migrate-my-oauth-client-to-new-api-scopes-and-minimize-impact-to-users%2Cwhat-if-i-have-several-apps-requesting-restricted-scopes-will-they-all-need-to-be-verified%2Cif-my-app-uses-a-combination-of-restricted-and-non-restricted-apis-will-i-need-to-submit-for-verification%2Chow-do-i-get-my-verification-completed-faster%2Cwhat-are-the-requirements-for-verification%2Cif-google-announces-additional-apis-that-fall-into-the-restricted-scope-category-do-i-need-to-re-submit-for-another-verification%2Cwhat-if-my-app-is-not-one-of-the-application-types%2Cwhat-type-of-applications-are-not-allowed-to-use-gmail-restricted-scopes%2Ccould-you-explain-the-limited-use-requirements-from-the-google-api-services-user-data-policy%2Chow-do-i-know-if-my-privacy-policy-does-not-meet-the-limited-use-requirements%2Cwhat-is-an-example-of-language-that-meets-the-limited-use-requirements%2Cwhat-if-my-privacy-policy-covers-multiple-types-of-data-including-non-restricted-scope-data%2Chow-can-i-make-my-privacy-policy-compliant-with-the-limited-use-requirements%2Cwhy-is-the-security-assessment-needed%2Chow-will-the-security-assessment-work%2Cwhat-if-my-app-accesses-google-user-data-through-oauth-api-scopes-that-arent-restricted-api-scopes%2Cwhat-will-the-security-assessment-include%2Cwhat-are-more-detailed-security-requirements-that-might-be-applied-during-a-security-assessment%2Cwhy-is-google-charging-a-fee-for-the-security-assessment%2Cif-i-have-gone-through-a-security-assessment-once-for-the-restricted-gmail-scopes-do-i-need-to-go-through-the-assessment-again-when-the-list-of-restricted-scopes-expands%2Chow-is-the-assessment-scope-impacted-if-my-application-sends-data-to-third-parties-for-processing-or-is-hosted-on-third-party-services-such-as-a-cloud-provider%2Cwhen-is-the-security-assessment-not-required%2Chow-long-is-the-security-assessment-valid-for%2Cwhat-should-i-do-after-i-receive-my-letter-of-assessment-loa-from-the-assessor%2Chow-do-i-prepare-for-my-annual-security-reassessment%2Cwhat-access-is-needed-by-the-third-party-security-assessor-for-the-deployment-review%2Cdoes-the-annual-security-reassessment-only-test-changes-ive-made-to-my-application-since-the-previous-assessment%2Cwhat-happens-if-i-dont-remediate-my-vulnerabilities%2Chow-can-i-submit-feedback-about-these-policies-and-changes)):

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.write
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.blood_glucose.read
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.blood_glucose.write
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.blood_pressure.read
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.blood_pressure.write
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body_temperature.read
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body_temperature.write
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.read
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.write
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.heart_rate.read
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.heart_rate.write
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.write
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.nutrition.read
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.nutrition.write
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.oxygen_saturation.read
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.oxygen_saturation.write
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.reproductive_health.read
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.reproductive_health.write
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.sleep.read
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.sleep.write

How to generate one is documented here : https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started#expandable-7